# How can I use a values of a list from one function to another function

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a set of values from the user and print max, min and mean values . But I cannot access the temperature values (t[]) I'm fetching in insert() outside . Can someone help me out .

I tried passing the list t as a argument in another function , but it says TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

```py
class TempTracker:
    def insert(self, temp):
        t = []
        self.temp = temp
        t.append(self.temp)
        return t

    def get_max(t):
        for i in t:
            print(i)

    def get_min():
        pass

    def get_mean():
        pass


a = TempTracker()
b = TempTracker()
temp = [1, 2]
a.insert(temp)
b.insert(3)
a.get_max()
```

I should get the max, min and mean of the list of values passed everytime

Comment: What are you passing to get_max? your method require `t` but your code doesn't provide an argument (last line)

Comment: I'm passing t inside while calling get_max() , but I'm getting the following error NameError: name 't' is not defined .

Comment: The first parameter if an instance method is the method receiver (normally called `self`). When you call `a.get_max()`, the `TempTracker` itself becomes your argument `t`, and that object cannot be iterated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your class so you have the values available in every class function. That way you can call the values by refering to self:

```
class TempTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = list()
        self.temp = None
    def insert(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp
        self.t.append(self.temp)
        print("test", self.t)
        return self.t

    def get_max(self):
        for i in self.t:
            print(i)

    def get_min():
        pass

    def get_mean():
        pass

def main():
    a = TempTracker()
    b = TempTracker()
    temp = [1, 2]
    a.insert(temp)
    b.insert(3)
    a.get_max()
```

This way you can also initialize your class with values instead of using insert:

```
def __init__(self, values):
        self.temp = values
        self.t.append(self.temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the definition of `get_max`. When you set its parameter as `t`, and no other parameter, then that `t` started working like the `self` in other functions you wrote in that class.

Actually, self is also just an identifier and nothing more. Thus when you tried to call `a.get_max()`, you passed `TempTracker`'s instance to the object attribute `get_max`, which then will try to iterate on the object itself, which isn't possible, since it isn't an iterator.

What you might have done:-

```
class TempTracker:
    t = []                  # moved t outside the insert's scope to prevent reinitialization
    def insert(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp
        self.t.append(self.temp)
        return self.t
    def get_max(self,):
        for i in self.t:
            print(i)
    def get_min(self,):
        pass
    def get_mean(self,):
        pass


a = TempTracker()
b = TempTracker()
temp = [1, 2]
a.insert(temp)
b.insert(3)
a.get_max()
```